# Serialize a json string as object with Serde

Tags: json, rust, serialization, serde

I have the following struct

```rust
#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    pub id: String,
    pub score: f32,
    pub json: String,
}
```

The `json` field always contains a valid JSON object already stringified.

Given an instance, I would like to serialize it with the JSON content.
Something like:

```rust
let a = MyStruct {
    id: "my-id".to_owned(),
    score: 20.3,
    json: r#"{
       "ffo": 4
    }"#,
};
let r = to_string(&a).unwrap();
assert_eq!(r, r#"{
        "id": "my-id",
        "score": 20.3,
        "json": {
            "ffo": 4
        }
    }"#);
```

NB: I don't need to support different serialization formats, only JSON.
NB2: I'm sure that `json` field always contains a valid JSON object.
NB3: commonly I use serde but I'm open to using different libraries.

How can I do that?

Edit:
I would like to avoid deserializing the string during the serialization if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`serde_json` has a `raw_value` feature for something like this:

`Cargo.toml`

```ini
# ...
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = { version = "1.0", features = ["raw_value"] }
```

`lib.rs`

```
use serde::{Serializer, Serialize};
use serde_json::{self, value::RawValue};

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    pub id: String,
    pub score: f32,
    #[serde(serialize_with = "serialize_raw_json")]
    pub json: String,
}

fn serialize_raw_json<S>(json: &str, s: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
where
    S: Serializer,
{
    // This should be pretty efficient: it just checks that the string is valid;
    // it doesn't parse it into a new data structure.
    let v: &RawValue = serde_json::from_str(json).expect("invalid json");
    v.serialize(s)
}

#[test]
fn test_serialize() {
    let a = MyStruct {
        id: "my-id".to_owned(),
        score: 20.3,
        json: r#"{
           "ffo": 4
        }"#
        .to_string(),
    };

    let r = serde_json::to_string(&a).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(
        r,
        r#"{"id":"my-id","score":20.3,"json":{
           "ffo": 4
        }}"#
    );
}
```

But the simplest (and most error-prone and least extensible) solution is simple string manipulation:

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    pub id: String,
    pub score: f32,
    // IMPORTANT: don't serialize this field at all
    #[serde(skip)]
    pub json: String,
}

fn serialize(a: &MyStruct) -> String {
    let mut r = serde_json::to_string(&a).unwrap();

    // get rid of trailing '}'
    r.pop();
    // push the key
    r.push_str(r#","json":"#);
    // push the value
    r.push_str(&a.json);
    // push the closing brace
    r.push('}');
    
    r
}

#[test]
fn test_serialize() {
    let a = MyStruct {
        id: "my-id".to_owned(),
        score: 20.3,
        json: r#"{
           "ffo": 4
        }"#
        .to_string(),
    };

    let r = serialize(&a);
    assert_eq!(
        r,
        r#"{"id":"my-id","score":20.3,"json":{
           "ffo": 4
        }}"#
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, but you have to override the default serialization behaviour somehow. You can do this either by wrapping your `json` field in a newtype (like `struct JsonString(String)` and implementing `Serialize` manually for that type, or you can use the [`#[serde(serialize_with = "...")]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#serialize_with) field attribute to ad-hoc change the serialization of the `json` field. Here's an example of using the `serialize_with` field attribute:

```
use serde::{ser::Error, Serialize, Serializer};

use serde_json::Value;

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    pub id: String,
    pub score: f32,
    #[serde(serialize_with = "as_json_object")]
    pub json: String,
}

fn as_json_object<S>(v: &str, s: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
where
    S: Serializer,
{
    let v: Value =
        serde_json::from_str(v).map_err(|_| Error::custom("error parsing serialized json"))?;

    v.serialize(s)
}

fn main() {
    let a = MyStruct {
        id: "my-id".to_owned(),
        score: 20.3,
        json: r#"{
           "ffo": 4
        }"#
        .to_owned(),
    };

    let r = serde_json::to_string(&a).unwrap();

    assert_eq!(r, r#"{"id":"my-id","score":20.3,"json":{"ffo":4}}"#);
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c2a22e84790666d4c1ab2ce9e6dbf473)

Comment: This solution involves `serde_json::from_str` that makes a deserialization with the performance issue. Is there a solution that doesn't involve JSON deserialization?

Comment: I think `as_json_object` could just be `let v: Value = ...; return v.serialize(s);`, or is there a difference to going through it manually?

Comment: @isaactfa, huh, so much more convenient. Thanks for pointing out, I've updated the answer

Comment: @allevo if you are hell-bend on doing it without deserialization, you could try and modify the resulting serialized string of `MyStruct`, removing the `"` around the json object stored inside the `json` field and replacing the escaped `\"` with `"`. I wrote a crude little regex for that. Never tried to do anything like that before, so please double check its correctness and use it at your own discretion: [playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e567e1ed81522b1a0038fb96d19f5a8e)